# How do you get the total row count of a surrealdb select query?

Tags: surrealdb

Using SurrealDB. is there a way that I can get the total amount of records for a query, like you would do in  traditional SQL databases?

```
select count(*) from person
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it would be

```
SELECT count() FROM person GROUP BY count
```

See more here: https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/functions/count